# SQL Server Intergration vs BI Intergratoin Services Project

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ssis

I receive the below error when I create a SSIS package. Which is telling me I need to install SSIS. This is confusing to me. SO what is the difference between creating a SSIS package using Microsoft Visual Stuidos BIDS and having SQL Server Intergration installed into SQL Server? I assummed they are the same.

```
Code: 0xC000F427
Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Lookup 1 of Integration Services or higher.
End Error
```

Comment: But I do have SSIS 2012 installed. For the referred question is says to load SSIS onto machine to resolve.My machine has 2012 installed.

Comment: How do I know if I have SSIS installed?